# ADC value (4000 to 20000) to (0-400) milibar conversion

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc, c, programming

I am getting full scale ADC value from 4000 to 20000. I am trying to convert o 0-400 mbar pressure, as I am ultimately measuring height of a tank.

I have a equation to measure the Height of Liquid.

Pressure Eq.

\$ L = \dfrac{P}{ \rho \cdot g} \$

\$ \rho = \rho_{0} \cdot SG \$

\$ SG = 1.033 \text{ (Specific Gravity of Milk)} \$

\$ \rho_{0} = 1  \text{ (Density of fresh water)} \$

\$ \rho = 1.033 \$

\$ P = \text{ADC Coutn To MiliBar Or Bar Value} \$

But how can I convert the ADC value to Milibar or Bar value?

Comment: Where is the equation for pressure?

Comment: Well in the ideal case you have a linear relationship between ADC value and pressure, so just draw a diagram, put the ADC values on the X-axis, the pressure values on the Y-axis. Put the points in there, connect them, think about how you get a formula out of it to describe what you just drawn.

Comment: If it is a linear relationship, google ```y=mx+c```.

Comment: I thought [linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) was mandatory prerequisite knowledge before studying programming...

Answer (score 1):

If your ADC goes from 4000 to 20000 it means you have 16000 point to mesure 400mbar.

Then the resolution of your mesure is:

resolution= 400/16000 = 0.025mbar.

And you have an offset of 4000 point.

Then your value in mbar is : P = (ADCvalue - offset) * resolution.